# How to get the file URL from ondrop event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following code for an uploader I'm making.

```
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
}
```

I want the user to be able to drag a file from the desktop onto the web browser, and then I want to capture it's location, so that I can manually upload it (Don't want to do the uploading through javascript) My question is though, how do I get the clients location of the file from the event, so that I can put it in a `<input type="file">` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of mozilla using the dataTransfer object of the event to get a list of files dragged

[EXAMPLE](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer#files)

My example:

```
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files.length != 0){
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files //Array of filenames
        files[0]; //the first file in the list

        // code to place file name in field goes here...

    }else{
        // browser doesn't support drag and drop.
    }

    console.log(e);
}
```

use the mozilla example because its more comprehensive than I've provided.

Answer (score 2):

The input file field can be treated as a normal input field and its value can be fetched as follows.

```
<input id="inputid" type="file" dropzone="..."> 

holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = $('#inputid').val();
    //split the string at the lastIndexOf '/' to get filename 
    console.log(e);
}
```